# Liberty Web application ViewExpiredException - No saved view state could be found for the view identifier

Tags: java, jsf, websphere-liberty, mainframe, cics

I've seen many posts for this similar case but I believe my issue may be different. I have figured out the cause but have not yet figured out how to fix it. I am running a 3 liberty servers in CICS in three different regions, all using the same bundle to launch the web application. The web application is fully operational and functions fine, but when all three servers are up and running in the three different regions, the application gets the ViewExpiredException. I have proven that this is why the issue occurs by shutting down two of the servers and attempting to replicate the issue with no success.

In regard to my code, I can post any if needed. As I said, the application is 100 percent operational, but only when one server is using it. All of my method classes are session scoped, except for my database operations class, which is application scoped. I believe workload management causes the current session to occasionally jump between servers, and doing so causes the error. If anyone knows how to fix this I will be very grateful. Thanks so much!

EDIT: I am posting the stack trace.

```
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /main.xhtml - No saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /main.xhtml
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:183)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1156)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1004)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:76)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:921)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:281)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:960)
at com.ibm.cics.wlp.impl.CICSHttpRunnable.run(CICSHttpRunnable.java:244)
at com.ibm.cics.wlp.impl.CICSTaskWrapper.runWork(CICSTaskWrapper.java:701)
at com.ibm.cics.wlp.impl.CICSTaskWrapper.run(CICSTaskWrapper.java:386)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the ViewExpiredException?

Comment: Yes. I am getting that exception and also an AJ05 aben in cics.

Comment: Using client side state saving will resolve this, as long as your application can tolerate the tradeoffs (more bandwidth, etc.)  I'm not very familiar with CICS, but if you're able to configure session persistence across servers/regions then the default server side state saving case should also work.

Comment: Thanks. It appears to have solved the issue. I am interested in the session persistence you mentioned and will research that. Thanks so much. I will approve my solution in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution. This issue may be due to the state saving method being set to server. I have added this to the web.xml of my code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To my understanding, since the application is jumping between servers, the exception occurs because the state saving method was server side, so it is lost when we travel to another server. Changing the method to client may resolve this issue.

I am currently attempting to replicate the issue. If I am unable to do so, I will select this as the solution.

Comment: Yes true. Using client side state saving would resolve this. This will invovle lot of network traffic data back and forth and ensuring security of state data using encryption. Alternatively you can consider a load balancer with sticky session enabled for the servers while using server side state saving. This is better approach when you want to have client sessions to hold states between requests.

Comment: You could also use 'session aware' balancer such as IHS with WebSphere Plugin, before your farm of Liberty. That would ensure that request from the same session would be directed to the same server.

Comment: Just Wanted to say thanks for the advice. The application is not in the working environments yet, so I will keep these thoughts in mind when efficiency comes into play.