# Is it ok to leave view state un-encrypted on a private network?

Tags: jsf, encryption, web-applications, viewstate, myfaces

Kind of general question. I have a web app running on a private network, only to be used by associates. The application runs on three different servers, but for some reason, throws a view state error, whenever workload management causes an open session to jump to a different server. Changing the view state saving method to client did not fix the issue, but doing that in addition to disabling the myfaces core encryption did, which i believe affects save state encryption. Being that this application runs on a private network, I am wondering if it is ok to leave the view states un-encrypted? The forms and submits contain no sensitive data, however, there is a login. No register new user either, only the login, as the credentials are derived from a different source, and that is the only sensitive data. Guidance would be greatly appreciated!To be more, clear, I'm wondering if anyone can explain to me whether or not this is a safe thing to do, and give me a reason as to why it is or is not safe.

Comment: So you checked if you use the same encryption Key on All servers And that is was the case

Comment: That I did. They all point to the same .keys. Now I am attempting to verify if there are any repercussions to leaving this as is on a private network.

Comment: I'd personally not leave it unencrypted indefinitly. Maybe for a short period and only over https untill the cause is found (I'd still think it is keys related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MyFaces 2.3.x, you can safely deactivate encryption when using server state saving. Even in public. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4133

However i would not turn it off for client side state saving.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, however a solution was found for my initial issue here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659014/
Now I no longer need to ponder at the risk. I would like to ask why you would not turn it off for client side saving in a private network, however.

Comment: because private doesnt mean trusted - its a security risk.